# Sending email with Azure logic app after triggering via httpRequest

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service

I've a azure logic app which contains two operations.

1. When a httpRequest is received.
2. Send email (v2)

I'm trying to send an email with the content of "task" when triggered by the httpRequest.

HttpRequest body json schema:

```
"properties": {
    "due": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "email": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "task": {
        "type": "string"
    }
},
"type": "object"
```

}

I've added the "task" object from the dynamic content in the body of the email. I want the body of the email to contain the content of the "task" sent in the httpRequest.

Below is how I'm sending the httpRequest with the required json data.  However, the email is always empty with no body. I must be doing something wrong. Any pointers would be appreciated.

```
await client.PostAsync(
               
            logicAppUrl, new StringContent(jsonData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
```

jsonData content:

```
{"email":"test@gmail.com","due":"4/1/2020","task":"content1-------------"}
```

Comment: What is the status now?

Answer (score 0):

You can debug with Postman what your json should look like. It seems that you 1) either forgot to include the curly braces in your string or 2) forgot to escape your double quotes in the string. It should look like

```
string jsondata = "{ \"email\": \"test@gmail.com\", \"due\": \"4/1/2020\", \"task\": \"content1-------------\"}"
```

**EDIT**:
If the json doesn't match, go to the logic app's HTTP task, click `Use sample payload to generate schema` and copy your json into it. In your case, it should be

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "email": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "due": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "task": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I copied from the Text visualizer hence it removed those escape characters. I'm sending the exact jsondata.

Comment: I see! You can open your logic app -> Overview and open your most recent run. Press `When a HTTP request is received -> Show raw outputs` to see what your json looks like when it's received. The properties should be within a `{ "body": { (...) } }` block.

Comment: Thanks Casper for the pointers. I'm looking at it right now but with no avail. I had already tried with using sample payload earlier with no avail. I have one run which worked couple of days ago and when I resubmit that run, it works. But I see no difference between that design and current one. There should be something missing...right now I'm flabergasted.

Comment: Can you see that the logic app has received json in the last run, and if yes, if it contains the right fields? Depending on that we know if we should debug the function app or logic app.